# Return Character in Function

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

char printBrowse(char choice);

int main(void) {
    char letter;
    printBrowse(letter);
    printf("-->%c", letter);
    getch();
}

char printBrowse(char choice) {
    printf("Welcome to Orange Movie Box\n\n");
    printf(" a)Browse by Name\n");
    printf(" b)Browse by Genre\n");
    printf(" c)Browse by Year\n");
    printf(" d)Browse by Age Rating\n");
    printf("Please choose your browsing method:");
    scanf("%c", &choice);

    return choice;
}
```

How to return choice from printBrowse to main? When I try to run this code, it works but when I print variable 'letter' it prints 'u' instead of 'c' when I input it on `printBrowse`.

Comment: Arguments passed by value are copied, so when you do `scanf("%c", &choice)`, you're actually storing the read value into the `choice` variable, whose scope is the `printBrowse` function. Now, you could change your code a bit: `char printBrowse(char *choice);`, `scanf("%c", choice);`, and call it as `printBrowse(&letter)`. This would work as you expect, although the return value method seems more intuitive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because when you are calling your function from main(), you are not storing the return value anywhere in the main() function.

```
int main(void)
{
    char letter;
    letter = printBrowse(); //storing the return value of printBrowse() function in letter variable
    printf("-->%c", letter);
    getch();
}
```

at the same time u can remove the parameter passing from the function printBrowse()

```
char printBrowse() {
    char choice;
    printf("Welcome to Orange Movie Box\n\n");
    printf(" a)Browse by Name\n");
    printf(" b)Browse by Genre\n");
    printf(" c)Browse by Year\n");
    printf(" d)Browse by Age Rating\n");
    printf("Please choose your browsing method:");
    scanf("%c", &choice);

    return choice;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use a return value:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char printBrowse()
{
   char choice;
   printf("Welcome to Orange Movie Box\n\n");
   printf(" a)Browse by Name\n");
   printf(" b)Browse by Genre\n");
   printf(" c)Browse by Year\n");
   printf(" d)Browse by Age Rating\n");
   printf("Please choose your browsing method:");
   scanf("%c", &choice);
   return choice;
}

int main(void)
{
   char letter = printBrowse();
   printf("-->%c", letter);
   getch();
}
```

Or you could pass the char by pointer:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void printBrowse(char* choice)
{
   printf("Welcome to Orange Movie Box\n\n");
   printf(" a)Browse by Name\n");
   printf(" b)Browse by Genre\n");
   printf(" c)Browse by Year\n");
   printf(" d)Browse by Age Rating\n");
   printf("Please choose your browsing method:");
   scanf("%c", choice);
}

int main(void)
{
   char letter;
   printBrowse(&letter);
   printf("-->%c", letter);
   getch();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, void printBrowse(char& choice), can you explain this line?

Comment: That's called 'pass by reference', but can only be used in C++, not C.

Answer (score 1):

Given the function signature, I believe you want to change your printBrowse function to this:
Your passing variable name letter to function printBrowse would not change the variable letter itself unless you pass the address of the variable &letter.

```
void printBrowse(char *choice)            //you pass the address of a char variable
{

  printf("Welcome to Orange Movie Box\n\n");
  printf(" a)Browse by Name\n");
  printf(" b)Browse by Genre\n");
  printf(" c)Browse by Year\n");
  printf(" d)Browse by Age Rating\n");
  printf("Please choose your browsing method:");
  scanf("%c", choice);

 }
```

Correspondingly, you main function need some changes to:

```
int main(void)
{
  char letter;
  printBrowse(&letter);
  printf("-->%c", letter);
  //getch();   sorry, I don't understand why you need getch() here.
}
```

Comment: you would use `getch();` to see the output before the program terminates

Comment: `getch` is used to see the final output else console may close before we can see the output